How can I transform between non-rotated and rotated coordinates to connect predefined points using \pgflowlevelsynccm
Credit:
https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/727949/319072
https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/729790/319072

I have two known 3d points in tikz, and would like to draw an arrow between them in perspective, using \pgflowlevelsynccm. How can I achieve this?
I know how to draw a circle in perspective for one such point using \tdplotsetrotatedcoordsorigin, but then we are stuck in the plane, and the already-known points move to different places when drawn in the plane (after using tdplot_rotated_coords and canvas is xy plane at z=0).
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
    \tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{130}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]
   
        % Plane equation: 1x + 2y + 3z = 4 (simplified for this example)
        \pgfmathsetmacro\nx{1}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\ny{2}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\nz{3}

        % Define z as a function of x and y
        \newcommand{\planeZ}[2]{(4-\nx*(#1)-\ny*(#2))/\nz}

        % Draw part of the plane
        \fill[opacity=0.3]
        (-1,-1,{\planeZ{-1}{-1}}) --
        (3,-1,{\planeZ{3}{-1}}) --
        (3,2,{\planeZ{3}{2}}) --
        (-1,2,{\planeZ{-1}{2}}) --
        cycle;

        % Compute Euler angles for rotating the z-axis to the normal vector
        \pgfmathsetmacro\yAng{atan(sqrt((\nx)^2+(\ny)^2)/(\nz))}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\zAng{atan((\ny)/(\nx))}
        \tdplotsetrotatedcoords{\zAng}{\yAng}{0}

        % Set the origin of the rotated coordinate system to a point on the plane
        \coordinate (Shift) at (1,1,{\planeZ{1}{1}});
        \tdplotsetrotatedcoordsorigin{(Shift)}

        % Draw an arrow in the rotated coordinate system to verify planarity
        \begin{scope}[tdplot_rotated_coords, canvas is xy plane at z=0]
            \pgflowlevelsynccm
            \draw[Circle->] (0,0) -- (-1,-1);

            % How can I transform between non-rotated and rotated coordinates 
            % to connect predefined points using \pgflowlevelsynccm:
            % Point 1: (1,1,{\planeZ{1}{1}})
            % Point 2: (-1,-1,{\planeZ{-1}{-1}})
        \end{scope}

        \coordinate (Shift) at (-1,-1,{\planeZ{-1}{-1}});
        \tdplotsetrotatedcoordsorigin{(Shift)}
        \begin{scope}[tdplot_rotated_coords, canvas is xy plane at z=0]
            \fill[red] (0,0) circle(0.1); % this is where the point should be
        \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



I believe this is related to my second point. The problem was the same: PGF/TikZ forgets the low level sync and doesn't revert it if you access the coordinate again.

We can calculate the components of two points before hand, and then calculate the Euler-angle matrix to get the plane level with our desired plane. Then we can use the dot product to find the angle between the line through our points, and the line through our initial point, and the point (1,0) in the new frame (calculated with spherical coordinates). We can then use our second z angle as this angle to get the desired orientation. Then, our answer is the line with x component being the length between out points, and the y component being zero.
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{130}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]

    % normal vector
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\nx}{1}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\ny}{2}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\nz}{3}

    % plane constant
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\d}{4}

    % Plane: z as a function of x and y
    \newcommand{\zPlane}[2]{(\d-\nx*(#1)-\ny*(#2))/\nz}

    % draw the plane
    \fill[opacity=0.3, save path=\outline] 
    (-5,-5,{\zPlane{-5}{-5}}) --
    (5,-5,{\zPlane{5}{-5}}) --
    (5,5,{\zPlane{5}{5}}) --
    (-5,5,{\zPlane{-5}{5}}) --
    cycle;
    \draw[use path=\outline];

    % point 1
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\pox}{2}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\poy}{2}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\poz}{\zPlane{\pox}{\poy}}
    \fill[red] (\pox,\poy,\poz) circle[radius=0.1]; % not oriented correctly, just to see the point

    % point 2
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\ptx}{-2}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\pty}{-1}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\ptz}{\zPlane{\ptx}{\pty}}
    \fill[red] (\ptx,\pty,\ptz) circle[radius=0.1]; % not oriented correctly, just to see the point

    % length between points 1 and 2
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\length}{sqrt((\ptx-\pox)^2+(\pty-\poy)^2+(\ptz-\poz)^2)}
    
    % tdplot rotated origin
    \coordinate (Shift) at (\pox,\poy,\poz);
    \tdplotsetrotatedcoordsorigin{(Shift)}

    % obtaining "some" unit vectors for our desired plane
    \pgfmathsetmacro\zAng{atan(\ny/\nx)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\yAng{atan(sqrt((\nx)^2+(\ny)^2)/(\nz))}

    \pgfmathsetmacro{\tdrotx}{\pox + cos(\zAng)*cos(\yAng)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\tdroty}{\poy + sin(\zAng)*cos(\yAng)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\tdrotz}{\poz + -sin(\yAng)}

    
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\zAngTwoNumerator}{
        (\tdrotx - \pox) * (\ptx - \pox) + 
        (\tdroty - \poy) * (\pty - \poy) + 
        (\tdrotz - \poz) * (\ptz - \poz)
    }
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\zAngTwoDenominator}{
        sqrt(
            (\tdrotx - \pox)^2 + 
            (\tdroty - \poy)^2 + 
            (\tdrotz - \poz)^2
        ) * 
        sqrt(
            (\ptx - \pox)^2 + 
            (\pty - \poy)^2 + 
            (\ptz - \poz)^2
        )
    }
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\zAngTwo}{acos(\zAngTwoNumerator/\zAngTwoDenominator)}
    
    \tdplotsetrotatedcoords{\zAng}{\yAng}{\zAngTwo}

    \begin{scope}[tdplot_rotated_coords]
        \pgflowlevelsynccm
        \draw[Circle->] (0,0) -- (\length,0); 
    \end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


